# Whats happening to my bmp colors?

Tags: image, file, bitmap, rgb, bmp

i was trying to use a bmp file as data storage (since my program uses 2d matrixes, this way would make editing saves easy without other tools, you just need paint), but i have a problem.
There are cases in which i have to check the precise color of a pixel, and i expect the user-created bmp file to have some specific rgb values.

At beginning i thought i was writing something incorrect in the file reading code, then i noticed the problem was somewhere else.

When i save the file with paint (or other programs too) the rgb value isn't kept exactly as it was inputted.

For instance, (0, 0, 5) becomes (0, 0, 0) once saved, (200, 0, 0) becomes (192, 0, 0) and so on; so when while reading i expect a 5 i get a 0 instead.

(i'm using 24-bit bitmap format).

How do i get around this?
Can i know what calculations are being done that change the colors, so i can correct it on the c++ code side, or is there anything i can do to make the savefile precise in 0-255 range?

Comment: Ugh! BMP and JPEG are awful intermediate formats for storing anything. I always prefer PNG or NetPBM.

Comment: ...after i spent half a day to read data from bmp xD
Do you have any library or copy-paste-able code to read png files into rgba matrix/array in c++?

Comment: I would suggest **CImg**. It is pure, modern C++, header-only and simple. Here are 4 lines that load 2 PNG images and paste one into the other and save the result... https://stackoverflow.com/a/37503938/2836621